# Detecting "Login as User" session

Tags: plugin-development

From a plugin, how would I go about detecting if an admin user is using the "Login as User" feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the way to do this would be to have your plugin listen for the [onBeforeLogin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userSession-onBeforeLogin) event.

From inside there, you'd check to see if the there is an existing session `craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn()` and the current user is an admin `craft()->userSession->isAdmin()`.

If both of those are true, I believe its going to be a pretty safe assumption that an admin just clicked the "Login as User" button.

Comment: To be clear, this is only detectable **at the moment of fake login?** Once the user has switched accounts, there's no way to distinguish between a real login and a fake login.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of any way to distinguish the two, currently. Ultimately they both end up using the same login logic.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the clarification!